# How to show a webpage from another webpage

Tags: php, html, forward

Here is the problem, I made my own webpage using apache and stuff. But the problem is that my internet (in the dormitory) doesnt allow it to be connected from outside.
so for example, using university wifi, i can visit my website typing ip address. but if I use cellular data, it cant.

But what I know is that our university offers webpage hosting to the students, not vps sadly. I can only upload files using ftp, but is it possible to use that webpage hosting to show my server to the world? since i can only upload files to the free webhosting, it must be possible only with htmls and phps, probably.

btw whats on my website is wordpress.

so maybe something like

`schoolfree.website.com/myname` will show me `123.456.789/`

and

`schoolfree.website.com/myname/home` --> `123.456.789/home/`
`schoolfree.website.com/myname/wp-admin` --> `123.456.789/wp-admin`

but simple redirecting wont work, obviously.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/joshdick/miniProxy looks like it can do what you want. And yes the term you should be searching for is "proxy"

Comment: Answer. It depends. Test and find out if you can access the internal sites from the free hosting. I would be sort of surprised if it could.

Comment: On the other hand, if your school allows you to host things, why don't you just upload your site directly there and avoid that flow?

Comment: I think it's worth a try to put it in an iframe on your "school webpage" - but I guess this would violate some security settings (or has other technical issues), so 1% chance of success with this :D

Comment: @apokryfos oh thats because size is extremely small so everything on my wp cant go up there. Thank you! ill try that soon tomorrow! and search through term proxy

Comment: @apokryfos it didnt work because
1. hosting only supports php4.4.7
2. "URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration"

But im pretty sure it will work if it wasnt the case. I'll just move to VPS i guess only $10 per month, thanks

Comment: @JihoonChung Yes, your school obviously does not want you to do this on their servers or over their internet, so fighting it may actually get you in legal trouble.